# Non full screen keyboard in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've seen games all around for android that allows you to type in-game. In landscape mode, the android keyboard would come up and take approximately only half of the screen.

On unity, this is not the case. If you call the keyboard on landscape mode, the full screen will be covered by the keyboard.

Is there a way that pushes up the 'half screen' keyboard?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, do you have solution?

Comment: Couldn't identify a solution! Let me know if you happen to resolve the issue.

Comment: Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Unity Ui in unity 5.2 which has Input Field Component
Work as an TextBox . As you will click on input field it will automatically call keyboard.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html

Half screen will be for keyboard and half will be your text area to write.